# Как передать PHP в HTML?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Есть нюанс, может подскажите если есть возможность, как правильно сделать? А то уже голову сломал...

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { 
if ( ! is_single() ) { 
echo '<div class="video"> 
    <iframe src="player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo 
    carbon_get_post_meta($current_episode->ID, 'crb_vimeo_video_id'); ?>" 
    width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" 
    mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""> 
    </iframe> 
    </div>'; 
 } 
}
```

Comment: что за код, откуда?

Comment: @InDevX        а это имеет значение? вопрос то не об этом )

Comment: А о чем вопрос? `echo '...<iframe src="player.vimeo.com/video/' . carbon_get_post_meta($current_episode->ID, 'crb_vimeo_video_id') . '" 
    width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"...';` - Об этом?

Comment: @Manitikyl     Да, я не знаю как в фрейм html вставить в таком случае php код

Comment: имеет значение)в некоторых случаях. вы внутри `echo` выводите строкой `<?php echo` а надо использовать конкантенацию `echo '<div class=...'. $str.'...';

Comment: @InDevX        могли бы вы написать как правильно должно выглядеть ?

Comment: @ТарасЛейтар я вам написал как правильно должно выглядеть, присмотритесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    if ( ! is_single() ) { 
        echo '<div class="video"> 
            <iframe src="player.vimeo.com/video/'.carbon_get_post_meta($current_episode->ID, "crb_vimeo_video_id").'" 
            width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" 
            mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""> 
            </iframe> 
            </div>'; 
     } 
}
```

Comment: И так тоже можно. Но в моем ответе читаемость кода лучше.

Comment: @KAGG Design   В обоих случаях 404 вылазит

Comment: 404 - это не к написанию кода вопрос, а к тому, что у вас в метаполе carbon. Посмотрите в консоли, увидите путь. Но к вашему вопросу это никак не относится.

Comment: @KAGG Design   Спасибо! Разобрался, а как теперь сделать чтобы только на одну страницу вывод работал, или по Titile или ID поста, а то if ( ! is_single('Episode 1') ) {  не работает

Comment: is_single('заголовок') работает только для постов. Если у вас страница, надо использовать is_page('заголовок')

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам третий вариант... Тоже рабочий :)
Я его предлагаю, потому что, он ближе к рекомендованному применению кода.

PHP очень удобен тем, что такую задачу как Ваша можно решить сразу тремя способами. Именно благодаря, такому "дружелюбному" подходу к разработчику PHP И стал одним из самых востребованных языков.

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        $varembed = carbon_get_post_meta($current_episode->ID, 'crb_vimeo_video_id');

        echo "<div class='video'> 
                <iframe src='player.vimeo.com/video/{$varembed}' width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen='' mozallowfullscreen='' allowfullscreen=''> 
                </iframe> 
              </div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Что такое "рекомендованное применение кода"?))

Comment: И код не рабочий. Вы когда пишете что-то, тестируйте.

Comment: Вежливым кодом принято считать код без замеса html и php... Знакомы со стандартом PSR-1 PSR-2?

Comment: Код поправил. Виноват. Забыл про экранирование... Не использую сам уже давно такие конструкции. Вообще лучше примитивный MVC чем такое смешение. И дело даже не в стандартах каких либо, а просто в множестве возможностей которых вы себя лишите, используя такой подход.

Comment: Что-то не припомню, чтобы PSR запрещали смешивание php и html. Можете дать ссылку на конкретное место в конкретном стандарте?

Comment: Кроме того, раз уж мы заговорили о стандартах, и находимся под меткой WordPress, то надо следовать WPCS. Ни в одном из представленных здесь ответов, включая мой, код не соответствует WPCS, потому что вывод не экранирован. Но в вашем случае будет наиболее затруднительно применить функцию типа esc_.

Comment: Ваша правда... Со стандартами виноват... Я новичок на Стаке. Буду больше внимания уделять меткам, что бы не оказываться в такой ситуации... А что касается PSR речь не о запретах, а о рекомендациях.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так:

```
<?php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        ?>
        <div class="video">
            <iframe
                    src="player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo carbon_get_post_meta( $current_episode->ID, 'crb_vimeo_video_id' ); ?>"
                    width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen=""
                    mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="">
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```